# error [error] Image: could not be loaded: file:/C:/Users/gskumar/Desktop/images/main.png

Tags: java, sikuli

```
import java.awt.Robot;

import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1
{

    static final int ACCEPTABLE_DELAY_LONG  = 5000 ;
    static final int ACCEPTABLE_DELAY_SHORT = 3000;
    Robot r;
    Screen event;
    RobotEvents re; 
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void Open() throws Exception
    {
        re=new RobotEvents();
        r=new Robot();
        event=new Screen();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplogon.exe");

        Thread.sleep(ACCEPTABLE_DELAY_SHORT);

        event.type("./images/main.png","personal");
        //event.type("images\\main.png","personal");
        //event.type("D:\\Project1\\Server\\images\\main.png","personal");
        Thread.sleep(ACCEPTABLE_DELAY_SHORT);

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the error message tell you that it can't find the image on the filesystem. You can try to change the path directory for the images using the following command:

```
 ImagePath.add(TestSikuli.class.getCanonicalName() + "/images");
```

And then, you have to change

```
event.type("./images/main.png","personal");
```

for:

```
event.type("/main.png","personal");
```